# Does bijective transformation conserve quantiles?

Tags: statistics

I am wondering the following, if I have a distribution p(x) and I want to transform it via a bijective transformation into p(z) (a gaussian or a uniform distribution, for example). and so z = g(x) and x = g^-1(z).

Does this bijective transformation preserve quantiles?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X\sim p_X$ is a continuous random variable with cdf $P_X$ that's supported on $\mathbb{R} $

It's not hard to show that $P_X(X)\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $(F^{-1}\circ P_X)(X)\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ where $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\mathrm{d}z$ is the CDF of a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution. So take $g$ to be either $P_X$ or $F^{-1}\circ P_X$ then set $Y=g(X)$.

If $y_p$ is the $(100p)^\text{th}$ percentile of $Y$ and $x_p$ the $(100p)^{\text{th}}$ percentile of $X$ then, since $g$ is increasing, we have $$p=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y_p)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq g^{-1}(y_p))$$ This shows $g^{-1}(y_p)=x_p$.